# How to center two overlapping circles within a div in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center two overlapping circles within a div but it's not working because of the style of margin-right -100. That is the style that is causing them to overlap. I have tried to set the style of margin: 0 auto on the div around it but it does not work. I've also tried to use some bootstrap and make columns to help center them but nothing is working so far. I've added a codepen down below for a proper demo.

```css
#projects {
 background-color: #3f4756;
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 15em; 
 padding-bottom: 10em;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

#projects h2{
 color: white;
 font-family: BrandonGrotesque, Brandon Grotesque;
 font-size: 3.75em;
 margin-bottom: 1.5em;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 500;
 letter-spacing: 2px;


}
.circle {
 display: inline-block;
 height: 30em;
 width: 30em; 
 line-height: 18px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 color: white;
 margin: 0 0 0 -100px; 
 

}

#projects > a:nth-child(3){ 
 position: relative;
 z-index: 1;
 background-color:#a3abbd;
 text-decoration: underline;


}
#projects > a:nth-child(2){ 
 position: relative;
 z-index: 2;
 background-color: #a4844e;
 text-decoration: underline;


}
#projects > a:nth-child(2) > p, #projects > a:nth-child(3) > p {
 margin-top: 4em;
 font-size: 3em;
 font-family: BrandonGrotesque, Brandon Grotesque;
 font-weight: 350;
 
 
}
```

```html
<div id="projects" class="skew">
     <h2>My Projects</h2>
     <a href="#" class="circle">
      <p>web</p>
     </a>
     <a href="#" class="circle">
      <p>graphics</p>
     </a>
 </div>
```

Comment: My codepen https://codepen.io/jennp1987/project/editor/DyenWe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if that is exactly how you wanted to center the circles so I centered both circles within a `div` in a row with one overlapping the other one slightly. [You can have a look here](https://jsfiddle.net/yhsw8uo5/1/) how it might look like.

You can see that I used [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) to achieve that result. I wrapped both circles in a `div` on which I used `display: flex`. On top of that, I centered the text of each circle within the `div`, using `display: flex` and related flexbox properties once again.

Obviously you could now play with the size of each circle depending on your preference.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I totally forgot about trying flexbox. Thank you.

Comment: Flexbox is great in my opinion. Glad it helped. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use flexbox in bootstrap 
just add class `d-flex justify-content-center` to the parent and maybe `align-items-center` also

Comment: this is a comment!